# SPI and pull-up resistors

Tags: arduino, i2c, spi

I have a breakout that comes with two 10kOhm resistors: one on the SDA and one on SCL. The chip takes a max of 3.6V. AFAIK, I2C needs pull-ups on its pins, but could SPI be used on this module? I'm powering it with an Arduino and SCL seems to be around 4.5V - is it too high or is the pull-up going to shift it down?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The schematic of the breakout is essentially this:

[image]

Comment: Which module? If the I/O pins are specified with a maximum voltage of 3.6v, then you cannot connect it to 4.5v directly.

Comment: It's a breakout of [LIS3DH](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00274221.pdf) . I've updated my question with the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the SPI bus, you need to remove the pull-up resistors.

You need to connect all wire lines like SDI, SDO, SPC and CS to the master device.

The LIS3DH is not 5V tolerant and the maximum voltage is 3.6V.
If you put higher voltage, you will damage the chip inputs.

You can put logic level translator between the Arduino card and your LIS3DH card.

Comment: Right. How come it's necessary to remove the pull-ups?

Comment: If the communications protocol is [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus), then pull-ups are not used and even detrimental. They are *required* for [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) however, as I2C only has [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) outputs, so can only pull a line low. Two different bus topologies, two different ways to communicate data.